# What is the equivalent of MKL's function "zgges" in Eigen C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen3, intel-mkl

What is the equivalent of MKL's "zgges" function in Eigen C++?

The "zgges" function computes the generalized eigenvalues, Schur form, and the left and/or right Schur vectors for a pair of complex and nonsymmetric matrices.

Comment: It's not supported but you can pass Eigen matrices to lapack: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Lapack

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for Eigen::ComplexSchur: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ComplexSchur.html

The two libraries don't always map one-to-one, so let us know if `zgges` does something you need but the above doesn't.

Comment: The link you mention is for a single complex matrix, but I am looking for a paire of complex matrices....